# Windows Mobile Application structure recommendations

Tags: performance, memory-management, windows-mobile

I need to create Solution Architechure for Windows Mobile and have following queries:

My application is like a service that will start in phone startup and that should run in background and have no UI (this is not a problem). I am using third party dlls (with source code) in my project. Does windows mobile have any problem of **loading dlls when we put the application in start-up**? If yes, should I include all souce code in my application (may be in AppCode folder)?

If I include all third party source code in application, my application executable size will be bigger. Will bigger size executable cause problem (slow mobile on startup or simply hang) if I put my application in start-up?

I have seen [this video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/ee725721.aspx) regarding starting applications quickly but seems that it does not apply to my case as my application does not have UI.

How should I create structure of my application such that loading application as service in start up will not have any issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps launched from the Startup folder actually launch pretty late - well after the shell is up.  So no, there are no issues with launching from there.  There are no problems with loading DLLs eitehr so you can put the library code in your app or leave it as a library - it makes no difference.